# What is the css-name of the blue elements, how do i find them

Tags: css, wordpress, colors, themes, customization

At the moment im creating a WordPress webpage, with the theme "attitude" from ThemeHorse. This theme has custom-css abilities in its non-pro-version, wich theoreticly allows me, changing its color. However, i dont find all css-names of its elements I need to change or dont know which kind of color-type i need to change.

http://themehorse.com/preview/attitude/

what i need is the css-element-name of all blue elements, button links and bars, also how i'm going to address them (so far, I only know color, border-color and background-color).

Comment: what do you mean by blue element?? And by inspect element or by using firebug you can get the element class/id...

Comment: you can search this color code for find that. #05a9c5

Comment: thanks for this tip, guess it will help a lot, but is there any like this addon for chrome?

Comment: nevermind, found firebug for chrome

Comment: Chrome has built-in "Inspect Element" - nicer to me than the Firebug. :) (Just right click and choose "Inspect Element")